# Nexus Error deleting snapshots due to insufficient disk space

Tags: nexus

It has failed to deploy a newer version of a deployment with the following error:

`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.8.2:deploy (default-deploy) on project finances-web: 
Failed to retrieve remote metadata com.finances.web:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml: 
Could not transfer metadata com.finances.web:2.1.7-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml from/to isban (http://nexus3:8081/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/): 
Failed to transfer file: http://nexus3:8081/nexus/repository/maven-snapshots/com/finances/web/2.1.7-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml. Return code is: 500 , 
ReasonPhrase:javax.servlet.ServletException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.OLowDiskSpaceException: 
Error occurred while executing a write operation to database 'component' due to limited free space on the disk (241 MB). The database is now working in read-only mode. Please close the database (or stop OrientDB), make room on your hard drive and then reopen the database. The minimal required space is 256 MB. Required space is now set to 256MB (you can change it by setting parameter storage.diskCache.diskFreeSpaceLimit) .?? DB name="component". -> [Help 1]`

I've tried to delete some files, to get some free space, howerver I got this error (on nexus web application):

`Error occurred while executing a write operation to database 'component' due to limited free space on the disk (1 MB). The database is now working in read-only mode. Please close the database (or stop OrientDB), make room on your hard drive and then reopen the database. The minimal required space is 256 MB. Required space is now set to 256MB (you can change it by setting parameter storage.diskCache.diskFreeSpaceLimit) . DB name="component"`

I cannot increase the space due to it is an external volume attached to a docker image.

What can I do?

Comment: Have you solved this problem?

Comment: I'm having the same problem. :(